# POST value becomes null after form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql

I have a a field with name `username`. I display the data on the second page using `$_POST['username']`. Below the displayed username is another form. When I submit that form, the page is refreshed and result is displayed on the same page. But what happens on the displayed username is that becomes null.

Comment: are ou sure that your form point to your second page ?

Comment: You need to post your code to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$_POST['username']` is nolonger in the post data. If you want to pass it along, create a hidden input on the second page with a name of "username" then set it's value to `$_POST['username']`

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username'];?>" />
```

Now when you submit your page, the "username" post variable will be available again.