# WordPress custom option within options array becomes null after saving

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom options page in my WordPress theme with many fields. I used to save each individual field as a separate option within WordPress. I have since updated to use a single option as an array. This method is working great, except when I want to have a sort of "read only" data stored in my options array.

One option is set somewhere else and I want to be able to see that data on this options page. This was working fine with the previous method. Now, when I save the options page, that particular option becomes null.

The only thing I've gotten to work is to give that input a name (thus making it no longer a "read only" field). Another solution would be to save it as a completely separate option. While these would work, I'd like to try to find a different method.

I've seen plenty of questions/tutorials for options pages, but none with this particular issue.

Here is an extremely simplified version of the code I'm using. You can see Option A has a "name" attribute and Option B does not (see comments in code).

```
<?php
    add_action('admin_init', 'register_my_custom_options');
    function register_my_custom_options(){
        $custom_options_defaults = array(
            'option_a' => '',
            'option_b' => ''
        );
        register_setting('my_custom_options', 'my_custom_options');
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
        settings_fields('my_custom_options');
        do_settings_sections('my_custom_options');
        $my_custom_options = get_option('my_custom_options');
    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Option A</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="nebula_options[option_a]" value="<?php echo $my_custom_options['option_a']; ?>" /><!-- This field can be updated like normal on this options page. When saving, it acts completely normal. -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Option B</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_custom_options['option_b']; ?>" /><!-- I only want this field to display the option that was updated elsewhere (see below) and not be able to be updated here. When the submit button is clicked, option_b will become null even after being set elsewhere. -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>

<?php
    //This code is triggered on a completely separate page.
    add_action('some_custom_action', 'update_my_custom_option_b');
    function update_my_custom_option_b(){
        $my_custom_options = get_option('my_custom_options');
        $my_custom_options['option_b'] = 'foobar';
        update_option('my_custom_options', $my_custom_options);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205887/post-value-becomes-null-after-form-is-submitted) may be what's happening to me, but I'll leave this open to see if there are other solutions for this particular problem.